# SQL Query to update if record exist in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have four MySQL database tables:

adults;    /// adults products 
kids;      /// kids products   
pets;      /// pets products   
jewelry;   /// jewelry products

Every product has a unique code value. I want to do search in these 4 tables and if code found in any of these tables update its quantity. What should I use?

I tried with IF exist but its quite hard to write it alone for beginner. I also tried to google for this solutions but didn't found anything for searching in multiple tables and updating values.

Comment: Bad design. Have one table (`products`), with all data. You can add a new column where you store product type (adult, pets etc.)

Comment: Could you please explain me why is it bad? Tables structures aren't identical.

Comment: With proper design you shouldn't even have started this question...

Comment: There's no such thing like all design are good/bad for all circumstances. I know some good reasons and good use cases whereby the tables need to be separated, so we shouldn't at all insist that it will always be a bad design to have the tables separated.

Comment: It is seperated because each product (kids or etc.) has different columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be efficient if you could update the table design as suggested for your existing design you could use Union all and if condition to solve your problem.

Here the example

```
select from (
select UCODE as UniqueCode from adults
union all
select UCODE from kids
union all
select UCODE from pets
union all
select UCODE from jewelry
) 
where UCODE = 'New_UCODE'
```